# JMeter test run not stopping after specified duration,will go endlessly without reporting error or logs

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter version 5.4.2 2022-08-03 12:29:03,767 INFO o.a.j.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_341
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

When I run from either command line or GUI for 40 users for 15minutes,test run will go on endlessly.
In jmeter log files it will show
2022-08-03 12:36:05,874 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Stopping because end time detected by thread:  but the run will continue for hours without reporting any error or any thing in the logs.
I have been observing this issue consistently.
There is no out of memory exception or any error,even the thread count used is less than 50,and no matter which mode of run I select this issue is persistent

Comment: Did you tried with latest version?did you tried without timers?

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case your application fails to respond and JMeter will wait for the response **forever**

So make sure to specify reasonable timeouts, for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the settings live under "Advanced" tab

[image]

If you have more than one HTTP Request sampler - it's better to use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices), this way you will be able to set the timeout for all HTTP Request samplers at one place.

If it doesn't help take a [thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump), this way you will be able to see what JMeter threads are doing and for what exactly they're waiting.

You can also forcefully terminate a running non-GUI test by running [`stoptest.cmd` script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/stoptest.cmd)

And last but not the least, [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page